# I need a div to be pushed down when several options from a dcc.dropdown menu have been selected (dash component, python)

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash

I am having trouble making the div below the 'multi' dropdown (dcc.dropdown from dash) to be pushed down when several options from the menu have been selected instead of overlapping as in the image below (or be sent to the back depending on the z-index). The dropdown is inside another div. I´ve tried changing css display and position with no positive outcome yet.

[image]

The code looks something like this:

```py
html.Div([
    html.Div(children=html.H2('SIMILAR PLAYERS', className='titulo_ventanah2'), className='titulo_ventana'),

    html.Div(children=[(html.I(className='search')),'Search by:'],style={'display':'inline-block','padding-left':'15%', 'font-size':'13px'}),

    html.Div(children=(dcc.Dropdown(style={'height':'20px', 'font-size':'14px'},persistence_type='session')),style={'display':'inline-block', 'padding':'0px 0px 0px 10px', 'width':'200px', 'margin-top':'5px'}),

    html.Div(children=(dcc.Dropdown(multi=True,style={'height':'20px', 'font-size':'14px'})),style={'padding':'0px 0px 0px 10px', 'width':'400px', 'margin-top':'5px'}, className='similardiv'),

    html.Div([
        html.Div(children=[html.Div(html.H3('Top 15 most similar players',className='titulo_ventanah3'),className='titulo_ventanaint'),

        html.Hr(),

        html.Div([children=dcc.Graph())])],className='similar_players'),
    ])
],className='container1')
```

There is also CSS code for some components:

```css
.container1 {
  position: fixed;
  width:80%;
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;  
  left:20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  top:0;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.titulo_ventana {
  top:0;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding-left:2%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.titulo_ventanah2 {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height:45px;
  color: #8f8f8f;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;  
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
}

.titulo_ventanaint {
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index:5;
  height:39px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}


.titulo_ventanah3 {
  max-width:100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
  line-height:45px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow:hidden;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
}


.similar_players {
  width: 97%;
  overflow: auto;
  height:540px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #002e5c;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top:1.5%;
  margin-left:1.5%; 
  display: block;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.similardiv {
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

I am hoping the solution is with a change in the display or position property of an element but I believe it has something to do with the default css for the dash component which can be found [here](https://github.com/plotly/dash-core-components/tree/master/src/components/css).

You can check out the dashboard in [link](https://fmatics.ew.r.appspot.com/similar)

If I change the position of the `.Select-menu-outer` to relative as suggested by CBroe in the comments, the following will happen only when the menu is opened:

[image]

Comment: _“You can check out the dashboard in link”_ - what I see there does not match the situation from your screenshot. The Attributes dropdown does not contain _any_ option, and typing & searching(?) does not appear to do anything either. If there are specific steps required to make this match what the screenshot shows, then you should explain what those are. Otherwise - provide a _proper_ example, please.

Comment: `.Select-menu-outer` appears to be absolute positioned, that is the container that shows "No results found" in your example. Overwriting that with `position: relative` makes the rest of the content move down - but also messes up the header display. And if I try to counter that, by applying vertical-align to those inline-block containers … then the effect of the mentioned element pushing the content down is lost again.

Comment: Sorry about the dashboard in the link, The dropdown menu is empty because de data is uploaded through a button somewhere else. I actually needed someone to look at the page source code like you did. I tried changing the position of `.Select-menu-outer` to relative but it doesn´t push down the div below, it only goes up as I will show you in the next edit I will make to the question

Comment: It does push down the content below. But because of the vertical alignment of these inline-block divs, the one next to it sits at the bottom, not at the top. (And as I said, trying to fix that by _specifying_ a different vertical-align than the default, seems to un-do the effect of relative positioning again.)

Comment: The problem now is that it only pushes down the div below when the dropdown is open. When it is closed it still overlaps even if the `.Select-menu-outer` has relative positioning. So it must be another class maybe?

Comment: How can it overlap when it is closed? Overlap what exactly?

Comment: As in the first screenshot I posted on the question. when I open de dropdown menu to see the options it pushes the div down (as in the last screenshot of my question), but when I choose the options I want and the dropdown menu is closed it looks exactly as in the first screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was to set the height of the dcc.Dropdown to 20px, by just deleting `'height':'20px'` the problem got solved